# Pair production

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electromagnetic-radiation, electrons

I have read following equation of pair production

Platinum + 2 gamma   -->   electron + positron

this equation I think obeys all laws and true.
But there are two books which are saying following equation

gamma --> electron + positron

On internet it is written that pair production is not possible in empty space. 
Clearly 2nd equation is not saying anything about the presence of non empty space while equation 1st is happening in the presence of a heavy metal Platinum i.e. non empty space. My question is that, is the 2nd equation true or not? Is there any case that 2nd equation holds true?
Please anwer in yes or no for both equations.

Answer (score 1):

In quantum electrodynamics, pair annihilation is,

$$e^- + e^+ \to \gamma + \gamma$$

which may occur at tree level, or beyond. For the process $\gamma \to e^- + e^+$ however, we have the following diagram at tree level:

[image]

The photon will have an interaction with say, a nucleus, because the process cannot proceed on its own without violating energy and momentum conservation.

To show this, assume the contrary. Then there exists a frame wherein $e^-$ and $e^+$ are emitted back to back, and the total momentum is zero, but $E_\gamma = pc > 2m_e$ for production, a contradiction.

Comment: JamalS, please see "Fundamentals of physics" by Jearl Walker, Resnick, Halliday, chapter 21, topic 21-3 Charge is conserved, equation 21-15. In that equation writer is wrting 2nd equation of my question, which is not possible. I just want to know why writer is writing wrong equation. I was having state board books  which are available only in my state. Iam replying now because now I have a book which is worldwide available. This book is also available as pdf.

Comment: @Gagan Saggu The second equation is, strictly speaking wrong, but it describes the essence of the phenomenon when a small energy-momentum jolt is provided by the platinum nucleus to make it possible. It is loose language assuming a well-meaning experienced reader. This answer is complete and correct.